# PHP -- How to Know if We're in a Specified Dir or a Child of a Specified Dir

Tags: php

The code below checks to see if we're in `COURSES_DIR` which I've defined elsewhere.

`if(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == COURSES_DIR)`

How can the code be modified to also apply to sub directories below `COURSES_DIR`?  For instance, `COURSES_DIR/sub/dir`.

Comment: Check if the current dirname begins with COURSES_DIR. Something along the lines of `strpos(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), COURSES_DIR) == 0`

Comment: @sal: That's straight genius!!  Thanks a bunch!  Want to submit an answer so you can get credit?

Comment: Glad to help. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the running script is in a subfolder of what's defined in `COURSES_DIR`, I would check if the *current* `dirname` path string begins with `COURSES_DIR`. Something along the lines of:

```
strpos(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), COURSES_DIR) == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

- use `opendir()` and `readdir` to get all the sub directories in the given directory;
- use `is_dir()` to identify whether the file is a directory;
- try to judge whether the given directory equals the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`;